# Реализация утильных классов для решения различных задач

Tags: java, ооп, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

Решаю множество маленьких и не очень задач для резюме. Очень часто во многих задачах повторяется функционал, например :

- конвертация;
- генерация рандомных данных (примитивных);
- считывание введенных пользователем данных;
- модели, которые встречаются во многих задач (массив - класс `Array`, точка - класс `Point`, и т.д.);
- фабрика для моделей.
- и т.д.

При написании утильных классов я создал иерархию классов используя различные паттерны, в особенности паттерн Command.
Классы, которые реализуют такой утильный функционал, используют множество преимуществ Java 8 и иерархии классов, они получились довольно удобными, расширяемыми и реализующими принципы ООП, а также многие из них параметризованы и могут работать с множеством типов данных.

Но для использования утильных классов необходимо создавать объект, а, насколько мне известно, утильные классы необходимо строить, используя статический контекст, а именно статические методы.

И теперь я не пойму какое из решений верное, более практичное и лучшее. Какую иерархию лучше использовать для утильных классов - объектную или статическую?

Comment: Слово "утильный" имеет смысл "свойственный утилю", "являющийся утилем". Ох уж эти беспощадные попытки перетащить в русский язык всё подряд.

Comment: Боюсь что общего ответа на вопрос нет. Клиентский интерфейс сильно зависит от поведения класса и сценариев использования.

Comment: Статическая реализация ≈ глобальное состояние ≈ зло. Строить какую-то иерархию основываясь на классах со статическим поведением - очень плохая идея (в 99% случаев).

Comment: Ну и при статической иерархии вы не сможете подмену одной реализации другой без изменения вызывающего кода.

Comment: Helper-классы, состоящие только из статических методов и не имеющие (не хранящие) контекста, использовать вполне можно. Можно ещё рассматривать идею создания класса, состоящего из констант (или просто readonly значений). Глобальная фабрика, вероятно, тоже окажется со статическим контекстом. Остальное всё лучше не привязывать к статике.

Comment: Уважаемые коллеги, большое спасибо за ответы и помощь. Насколько я понял, то моя нестатическая иерархия, изначально была верным решением, просто подправлю её. Огромное спасибо.